# What should i do to fix the position of footer in my ionic 3 application?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, footer, mobile-application

In my ionic 3 app, when i click on the input field, then keyboard is open and my footer change it's position and it come above the keyboard.
i want to fix the layout of ionic 3 app, when keyboard is open, it should not change.

Answer (score 0):

When your platform is ready, you can set the keyboards disableScroll to true. Something like this:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Here I'm using the keyboard class from ionic native.
  Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
});
```

Also in your ngModule make sure you make this change:

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { scrollAssist: false, autoFocusAssist: false } )
```

Comment: Hi @Vinod Bhavani, i dont understand, how to use your code, please tell how can i use your code

Answer (score 0):

@Vinod's answer disables the keyboard scrolling completely. I'm guessing you're willing to move the whole view *except* the footer. (Since you want the user to have the text field visible whenever they fill in their info).

You could simply use CSS for this, set the footer to:

```
.footer, ion-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if you're using an `ion-footer` or simply a div with a `.footer` class. Change the above snippet accordingly